# Lines overlapping in R with ggridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ridgeline-plot, ggridges

I use ggridges in R to visualize my data. But a lot of the lines are overlapping and are hard to read.

[image]

My code is:

```
ggplot(task1, aes(x = ibu, y = style, fill = style)) +
  geom_density_ridges(alpha=1) +
  theme_ridges() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

What should I change to make this visualization more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `scale` parameter to adjust the overall height scaling. Just set it to a number that produces results you like.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggridges'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     scale_discrete_manual

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 0.5)
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>